# How to buy self-created ERC-20 token via simple transaction?

Tags: remix, metamask, gas, contract-invocation, rinkeby

Pretty sure that this is something newbie, but here is the problem:

- I created smart contract
- I got initial balance using official faucet of Rinkeby network and Metamask
- I deployed contract using Remix and Metamask to Rinkeby network

Now I just simply want to send transaction (some 0.1 of ETH) and get back some of my test token, like 0.1 for instance.

Here are my 2 contracts:

- 0x8F228268423D5c535A5b316d0f84a6A2D84f242E
- 0xf347712bc3cDBF1464C902B6C00111d998f615BF

**The problem is that** when I send some ETH to the contract I get constant error, which I do not know how to solve.

> "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [out of gas] "

e.g. this transaction https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x571f15295cd2ee825d474c4b97a87b2bfd2ffbcff7e9f518f19d174854bc66c9

What am I doing wrong?

I just want to send some of my test generated ETH to the my contract. I have 18 ETH, this is over than enough for the gas to pay, what is the issue?

Comment: Hey Oleksandr, welcome to StackExchange. Can you paste the code of the contract?

Comment: The error show you are running out of gas, you need to increase the limit to finish the execution. 21k gas is usually only enough for simple value transfers

Comment: Sure this is the gist with both contracts https://gist.github.com/AlexanderTserkovniy/d506d3e306f51e6b75bf72b77433eeb5. @AndriyLysak No this is not the issue, because I've been put all possible values to the gas, from 1 to 300000000, still no luck. Might be an issue in some setting of Metamask or something else, but not in the amount of gas itself.

Comment: Hey @PaulRazvanBerg could you take a look? https://gist.github.com/AlexanderTserkovniy/d506d3e306f51e6b75bf72b77433eeb5